# how to locate vim which installed by brew?

Tags: vim, osx, homebrew

I have installed a vim using brew, and it was installed to a very different place, and now I want to locate that vim, in a shell script, is there a good approach for this?

Comment: `brew info vim` can give you the information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should find the newly installed vim in the `bin` directory under the homebrew prefix:

```
echo `brew --prefix`/bin/vim
```

Certainly `brew info vim` will tell you what cellar `brew` installed `vim` into. Since I haven't installed `vim` using homebrew, let me show you an example using `wget`:

```
benlavery@Talantinc:~ $>brew info wget
wget: stable 1.16.3, HEAD
Internet file retriever
https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/wget/1.14 (8 files, 716K)
  Built from source
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/wget/1.15_1 (9 files, 908K)
  Built from source
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/wget/1.16 (9 files, 920K)
  Built from source
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/wget/1.16.1 (9 files, 940K)
  Built from source
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/wget/1.16.3 (9 files, 1.5M) *
  Built from source
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/wget.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: xz ✔
Recommended: openssl ✔
Optional: libressl ✘, pcre ✘
==> Options
--with-debug
        Build with debug support
--with-iri
        Enable iri support
--with-libressl
        Build with libressl support
--with-pcre
        Build with pcre support
--without-openssl
        Build without openssl support
--HEAD
        Install HEAD version
```

You can see the most recent version marked with an asterisk (*).

So for me, `wget` was installed into

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/wget/1.16.3/bin/wget
```

I can now use `find` to search for where homebrew symlinked `wget`:

```
benlavery@Talantinc:~ $>find / -lname *Cellar/wget/1.16.3/bin/wget 
/opt/homebrew/bin/wget
```

Notice I've used `*Cellar/wget/1.16.3/bin/wget` as the `lname` and not the full path. Homebrew links the files relative to their install, so if we used the full path we wouldn't have caught `../Cellar/wget/1.16.3/bin/wget`.

I now know that `/opt/homebrew/bin/wget` is what I should use in my script.

As I said, this is using `wget`, the same process can be used to investigate where `vim` is.

Answer (score 2):

If the newly installed vim is your current vim:

```
echo `which vim`
```

If you want to override system vim with brew:

brew install macvim --override-system-vim

If you want to play with paths in a script, I'd recommend reading this q/a:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21694327/installing-vim-with-homebrew

Comment: no that  won't help, because the brew install at a different place, so which vim only find a vim in /usr/local/bin